# Xcode7 blank webview error

Tags: webview, uiwebview, ios9, xcode7

I've developed an iOS web-app for Xcode 5.
now I've shifted to Xcode 7 for testing it on my friend's mobile which has ios9.
so now i tried to run same app in Xcode 7 but its showing blank screen. I've tried adding keys in plist.. still no lucks.Please Help

Answer (score 0):

I think we need more info to answer your problem:

- Did you use .xib files for your project?
- Is it using Objective-C or Swift?

On my end, I am using Xcode7.1.1 with Swift and in this version, I am using storyboards where I have a web view. The path for the web view content is defined on my *ViewController.swift* and connected via/through *Connections Inspector*

Comment: I am using obj-C , after googling around it told me to add exceptions in the plist to display any url with http. Tried adding exceptions still no lucks.. not yet.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Objective-C layouts :-S. So far for layouts in Swift, the term I encounter is constraints, not exception. They can be set using the pin tool at the bottom of the storyboard display. This can be set to ensure that objects in your app are viewable regardless of the layout and device you use. You may use the Assistant Editor to view where your web view falls on different devices without the need to relaunch the app. Please check as well if the webview controller content is defined in the viewcontroller file, and connection is already defined under Connections Inspector.

Comment: first.. thanks for reply.And yes webview controller content is defined in the viewcontoller file. Also the connection is already defined in connection inspector.

Comment: finally after days of search, shifted all the code to Xcode 7,from scratch.